# Have to press the same key 5 times to move once C#

Tags: c#

So essentially, the character is a 7 in a 2d array of 0's I can move it around in the array, but I have to press the key five times to move once.   Anybody know how to fix this?

```
  public class Dwarf
    {
        public int x = 5;
        public int y = 5;

        public void Move()

        {
           if(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.W)
            {
                y--;
            }
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.S)
            {
                y++;
            }
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                x++;
            }
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.A)
            {
                x--;
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Can also share how are you using this class?

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call `Console.ReadKey`, the program will retrieve input. The way you have your code written right now, it's always being called for every key you're checking for. What you need to do is call the method once, store the result, and have your logic use that instead:

```
var keyPress = Console.ReadKey(true);

if (keyPress.Key == ConsoleKey.W)
{
    y--;
}
//etc
```

Comment: Thanks, thats fixed the problem a bit, it has gone from 5 presses to 2. Any chance I can get it down to one press?

Comment: You are going to need to show your code (not just the stuff you show above (fixed), but the code that calls it).

Comment: @MatthewHeron You have something else that is blocking for input then.  The important thing to note is `Console.ReadKey` _blocks_.